# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed

Tags: java, ssl, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

My company runs an old application built in ColdFusion MX7.0.2, running Java 1.4.2. I can't upgrade ColdFusion because CyberSource doesn't support anything higher than MX7.

When calling the CyberSource Simple Order API (https://ics2wsa.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/) I get an error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature
>   validation failed

and also at the bottom of the output:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
>   Signature not available

I've checked to see that CyberSource's certs are in the keystore, and they are. Someone told me I need to upgrade the version of java. I installed jdk1.6.045 and pointed ColdFusion to it but it errors as well:

> Error: Cannot perform web service invocation runTrans.
>
> Details: The fault returned when invoking the web service operation
>   is: AxisFault  faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP 
>   faultSubcode:   faultString: (500)Internal Server Error  faultActor:
>   faultNode:   faultDetail:     {}:return code:  500
>
> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

I'm at a loss. Any help would be great.

Chris

Comment: I'm not familiar with CyberSource, but if they are simply providing a SOAP API that you are consuming, they do they care what language you are using (or version of that language)? ColdFusion MX7  (as great as a product as it was) has been EOL'ed so long ago there's no reason to use it (especially Java 1.4!)

Comment: This statement, `CyberSource doesn't support anything higher than MX7`, might not be true.

Comment: As Brad mentioned, both MX7 and Java 1.4 were EOL'd (not to mention, MX probably does not support newer versions of java). Searching suggests it might be an SSL issue with the cert and jvm. Try it with a newer version of CF that does support newer versions of java. s. Both [ACF](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/installing-coldfusion-express.html) and [Lucee](http://lucee.org/downloads.html) have Express versions you can download and use for quick tests.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had some golden ticket. This issue resolved itself! CyberSource said it couldn't be anything on their end, but I changed nothing. Draw your own conclusion.